# Calculating all inside geographic bounding boxes inside bounding box

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to do a function that retrieves all bounding boxes inside a bigger bounding box given a zoom level on react-native-maps. The issue is that it keeps timing out and worse, it does not return appropriate values.

I think it's because of the way I compute the degrees / pixel, since I seem to get values that make little sense.

Is there a better, more sane way to do this? And, if so, how?

Appreciate any help in this matter...

```
const EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;
const KM_IN_METERS = 1000;


/**
 * Function to convert degrees to radians
 * @param {number} degrees - degrees to convert to radians
 * @return {number} radians - radians converted
 */
function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

/**
 * Returns haversine distance in meters
 * @param {*} lat1 - latitude of point 1
 * @param {*} lon1 - longitude of point 1
 * @param {*} lat2 - latitude of point 2
 * @param {*} lon2 - longitude of point 2
 */
function haversineDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

  //Calculate differences
  const diffLat = toRadians(lat2-lat1);
  const diffLon = toRadians(lon2-lon1);

  //Calculate haversine coeficients
  const a = Math.sin(diffLat/2)**2 + Math.cos(toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(diffLon/2)**2;
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  
  //Return distance
  return EARTH_RADIUS_KM * c * KM_IN_METERS;

}

/**
 * Returns middle coordinate between two coordinates
 * @param {number} lat1 latitude of point 1
 * @param {number} lon1 longitude of point 1
 * @param {number} lat2 latitude of point 2
 * @param {number} lon2 longitude of point 2
 * @returns object { lat: number, lon: number } with middle point coordinates
 */
function middleCoordinate(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

  const diffLon = toRadians(lon2-lon1);
  lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
  lat2 = toRadians(lat2);
  lon1 = toRadians(lon1);

  const dx = Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(diffLon);
  const dy = Math.cos(lat2)*Math.sin(diffLon);

  const midLat = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + dx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + dx) + dy**2));
  const midLon = lon1 + Math.atan2(dy, Math.cos(lat1)+dx);

  return {
    lat: midLat,
    lon: midLon
  };
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {*} upperBoundingBox - northwest bounding box (upper limit) { lat: number, lon: number, latDelta: number, lonDelta: number }
 * @param {*} lowerBoundingBox - southeast bounding box (lower limit) { lat: number, lon: number, latDelta: number, lonDelta: number }
 * @param {*} zoom - zoom level 0 to 20
 * @returns array with center point coordinates: [{upperLat: number, upperLon: number, lowerLat: number, lowerLon: number, centerLat: number, centerLon: number}]
 */
function getSubBoundingBoxesCenterPoint(upperBoundingBox, lowerBoundingBox, zoom) {

  //Get screen dimensions
  const width = 392.72, height = 777.45;

  //Get points
  const { lat: lat1, lon: lon1, latDelta: latDelta1, lonDelta: lonDelta1 } = upperBoundingBox;
  const { lat: lat2, lon: lon2, latDelta: latDelta2, lonDelta: lonDelta2 } = lowerBoundingBox;
  
  // Calculate the distance per pixel for latitude and longitude
  const latitudeDistancePerPixel = latDelta1 / height;
  const longitudeDistancePerPixel = lonDelta1 / width;
  console.log(latitudeDistancePerPixel, longitudeDistancePerPixel)

  // Calculate the height and width of the bounding box in meters
  const heightMeters = haversineDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon1) / latitudeDistancePerPixel;
  const widthMeters = haversineDistance(lat1, lon1, lat1, lon2) / longitudeDistancePerPixel;
  console.log(heightMeters, widthMeters)

  // Calculate the number of sub-bounding boxes based on the zoom level (e.g., 2 ^ zoom)
  const numSubBoxes = Math.pow(2, zoom);

  // Calculate the step size for latitude and longitude for each sub-box
  const stepLat = heightMeters / numSubBoxes;
  const stepLon = widthMeters / numSubBoxes;

  // Calculate and store the center points of each sub-box
  const centerPoints = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numSubBoxes; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numSubBoxes; j++) {
      const subBoxUpperLat = lat1 - i * stepLat;
      const subBoxUpperLon = lon1 + j * stepLon;
      const subBoxLowerLat = subBoxUpperLat - stepLat;
      const subBoxLowerLon = subBoxUpperLon + stepLon;
      const centerPoint = middleCoordinate(subBoxUpperLat, subBoxUpperLon, subBoxLowerLat, subBoxLowerLon);
      centerPoints.push({
        upperLat: subBoxUpperLat,
        upperLon: subBoxUpperLon,
        lowerLat: subBoxLowerLat,
        lowerLon: subBoxLowerLon,
        centerLat: centerPoint.lat,
        centerLon: centerPoint.lon
      });
    }
  }

  return centerPoints;

}
```